# Canvas touch support, positioning the touch event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, html5-canvas

## What is the problem

I'm building kind of drawing app using Vuejs. While doing so I encountered a problem with touch event positioning. What I mean is that every time I try to draw something with touch simulation in the browser the line is drawn about 300px below the touch point. This code works perfectly without touch simulation but unfortunetely I need touch-support. Thank you for every kind of help!

### Canvas in the DOM

```
<tempalte>
    <canvas ref="Canvas" id="canvas" width="350" height="350">
</template>
```

### Canvas in the vue template

```
const Canvas = ref('');

    
const state = reactive({
      canvas: '',
      isDrawing: false,
      X: '',
      Y: '',
    })

onMounted(() => {
      let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
      let context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      state.canvas = context
      Canvas.value.addEventListener('touchstart', beginTouchDrawing, false);
      Canvas.value.addEventListener('touchmove', TouchDrawing, false);
    })
```

### Events functions

```
function beginTouchDrawing(event) {
      state.isDrawing = true
      let pos = touchPose(event)
      drawLine(pos[0], pos[1])
      state.X = pos[0];
      state.Y = pos[1];
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    
function touchPose(e){
        if (e.touches) {
          if (e.touches.length === 1) { // Only deal with one finger
              let touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1
              return [touch.pageX - touch.target.offsetLeft,
              touch.pageY - touch.target.offsetTop]
          }
        }
    }


    
function TouchDrawing(event) {
      if (state.isDrawing) {
        let pose = touchPose(event)
        drawLine(state.X, state.Y, pose[0], pose[1]);
        state.X = pose[0];
        state.Y = pose[1];
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

### Drawing the line

```
function drawLine(X, Y, newX, newY){
      let ctx = state.canvas
      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(X, Y);
      ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    }
```

#### Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the canvas position you must sum the offsetTop/offsetLeft of all the canvas parents

```
function touchPose(e){
    if (e.touches) {
      if (e.touches.length === 1) { // Only deal with one finger
          let touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1
          let offset = getOffsetSum(touch.target);
          return [touch.pageX - offset.x,
          touch.pageY - offset.y]
      }
    }
}

function getOffsetSum(element) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;

    if (element.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += element.offsetLeft;
            curtop  += element.offsetTop;
            element = element.offsetParent;
        } while (element);
    }

    return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly with the y axis, but it doesn't with x axis. I mean the beginning is shifted to the left by 100px.

Comment: I solved this issue by hard-coding ` touch.pageX - offset.x + touch.target.width / 2 `